# jsrender external templates not getting rendered

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jsrender

I have a MVC project. I am new to jsrender and try to render it.

I have a js file which contains all the jquery function. so i have put my template in there as well. The code for that looks like:-

```
function doSomething(){
var movies = [
        { name: "The Red Violin", releaseYear: "1998" },
        { name: "Eyes Wide Shut", releaseYear: "1999" },
        { name: "The Inheritance", releaseYear: "1976" }
    ];

$.when($.get('../Views/Hr/Templates/_mytemplates.tmpl.html'))
        .done(function (tmplData) {
            alert(tmplData);
            $.templates({ tmpl: tmplData });
            $('#divload').html(
                $.render.tmpl(movies)
            );
        });
}
```

The js file is located in the Scripts/myScripts folder.

I am not able to render this template.

Can anybody explain why i am having the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide alert output in question as well?

Comment: i don't get anything from the alert

Comment: Try using firebug or Chrome's developer tools (F12) and see if the template file is fetched successfully